# Windows 10 - Enabling ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING underlines all lines in cmd

Tags: c++, windows, console

In order to get colored text output using escape characters using Windows, you have to enable the flag. I am able to enable the flag, but doing so underlines every single line in the console, even lines printed before `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` was enabled (Which is the flag used to turn on colored output).

```
CORE_INFO("Output before ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is enabled");
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    CORE_ERROR("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE: %d", GetLastError());
    return;
}

DWORD consoleMode = 0;
if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &consoleMode)) {
    CORE_ERROR("GetConsoleMode failed: %d", GetLastError());
    return;
}

consoleMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, consoleMode)) {
    CORE_ERROR("SetConsoleMode failed: %d", GetLastError());
    return;
}
CORE_INFO("Output after ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is enabled");
```

Here is the output of the code after being ran: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK8ER.png

Closing the application reverts the console back to normal, with the coloring staying in place: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w386n.png

Stepping though the code line by line, all the lines become underlined once `SetConsoleMode(hOut, consoleMode);` is called, which leads me to believe that it's an error with how I enable the flag, but I'm following what MSDN says to do. I can't link it because I don't have enough rep.

If anyone has some insights as to why this is happening I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your syntax highligter is not the compiler. Why do you care what it does (except for estethic reasons)?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what this is. For a project I'm working on I'd like to have colored output in console, simply because it looks nice, and it's easier for me to tell if I have an error. This has nothing to do with my syntax highlighter or compiler.

Comment: What happens if you clear the screen just before setting the flag?  How about just after?

Comment: Clearing before and after both have all the empty lines underlined. Every line is underlined, even those without text